# getting a Repository moved permanently error but URL seems to be valid

Tags: svn, netbeans

I am new to svn. I am trying to import [this](https://plib.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/plib) project into netbeans. When I go the the URL, a web page shows up. But when I import it into netbeans (Team-->Subversion-->checkout) I get this error:

```
org.apache.subversion.javahl.ClientException: E175011: Repository moved permanently; please relocate E175002: PROPFIND request failed on '/svnroot/plib/!svn/vcc/default'
```

Do I need to feed netbeans the URL for the [trunk](https://svn.code.sf.net/p/plib/code/trunk/)? How is that different from feeding netbeans the URL for the whole repo? Why am I getting an error about "Repository moved permanently" even though the URL is valid?

I trying to build [flightgear](http://wiki.flightgear.org/Howto%3aBuild_FlightGear_with_NetBeans_using_CMake#Installing_required_modules_.28plugins.29) and don't really know the code base (plus I am new to SVN) so I am a little hesitant to deviate from the written instructions (which call for the root URL) without really understanding what is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do I need to feed netbeans the URL for the trunk?

Yes, and this is clearly written on FlightGear wiki page

> You will need to check out (with git it's called "cloning") the repositories for the following dependencies:
>
> ...
>
> PLIB http://svn.code.sf.net/p/plib/code/trunk
>
> How is that different from feeding netbeans the URL for the whole repo?

You checkout **different trees** in these cases

> Why am I getting an error about "Repository moved permanently" even though the URL is valid?

Valid URL for web-browser (which doesn't speak WebDAV) doesn't mean valid resource for SVN-client (which **speak** WebDAV)

Answer (score 0):

You used this url:
https://svn.code.sf.net/p/plib/code/
then try this url:
https://svn.code.sf.net/p/plib/code/trunk/

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.